# Function' object has no attribute 'objects' in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

**Views.py**

```
def posts(request,slug):        
    post=blogpost.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    comment=blogcomment.objects.filter(post__in=post,parent=None)
    replies=blogcomment.objects.filter(post__in=post).exclude(parent=None)
    redict={}
    for reply in replies:
        if reply.parent.sno not in redict.keys():
            redict[reply.parent.sno]=[reply]
        else:
            redict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)
    context={'post':post,'comments':comment, 'redict':redict}
    return render(request,'blog/blogpost.html',context)
```

Please help me in solving this problem.

**Error**

```
   Exception Type: AttributeError at /blog/1st-blog
   Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: You likely made a view named `blogcomment` and thus do not reference the model but the view.

Answer (score 0):

You likely made a view named `blogcomment` and thus do not reference the model but the view. You thus should change the name of that view, or rename the model.

Usually the name of a model is written in *PascalCase*, so `BlogComment` instead of `blogcomment`. You thus might want to simply change the name of the model, and change references to that model accordingly.